# Changing nav opacity without affecting tabs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav menu and I want to make its background transparent without affecting the tab's background - but it won't work. When I use `opacity`, the whole nav becomes transparent, even the tabs. When I use `rgba`, it doesn't go transparent at all.

Here is my code:

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
ul.nav.nav-tabs li {
  background-color: #6FD508;
}
ul.nav.nav-tabs li a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: [Seems to be working...?](https://jsfiddle.net/keewvfk7/)

Comment: I completely dont know what he wants. Perhaps he wants `background-color:transparent` ? https://jsfiddle.net/keewvfk7/1/

Comment: I want to menu color to black and reduce its opacity not to make it transparent

Comment: Then, what is the problem? Your code works fine

Comment: it doen't work for me

Comment: @Pain Can you explain it a bit more detailed? Maybe a screenshot with desired output will be great in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this its already working. Because there was nothing behind the `<ul>` so its was just showing flat grey color but if you noticed the you have applied black color still it was showing grey color because of transparency.

Adding `.dummy` div as parent of `<ul>` with red background color. Now you can see the area behind the `<ul>` is different red color. If `<ul>` don't have transparency then it should not show `.dummy` div color.

```css
ul.nav.nav-tabs {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
ul.nav.nav-tabs li {
  background-color: #6FD508;
}
ul.nav.nav-tabs li a {
  color: white;
}
.dummy{
  background:red;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dummy">
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active">
     <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">tab1</a>
   </li>
   <li>
     <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">tab2</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

> Try adding come image or other element to let transparency show exactly because on white background transparency is working but effect is not proper.

Comment: I tried my code on Bootply it works fine, it just doesn't work on my website

Comment: do u have any link for that?

Comment: bro you have to show me something...how can i rectify the bug then?

Comment: always use `position:relative` with negative margin. `ul.nav.nav-tabs {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border: none;
    margin-top: -41px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    position: relative;
}`